# When one function failure and then go to next function success, will occur loop back in cmd batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

I have a question.

My expected workflow is below.

IF PINGA **fail** --> PINGB --> PINGC --> PINGD --> PINGDRIVE

IF PINGA --> PINGB **fail** --> PINGC --> PINGD --> PINGDRIVE

IF PINGA fail --> PINGB --> PINGC **fail** --> PINGD --> PINGDRIVE

IF PINGA fail --> PINGB --> PINGC --> PINGD **fail** --> PINGDRIVE

According to the workflow, if one of PING (e.g. A) is failure, then go to PINGB, after PINGB finish, go to PINGC, etc... until to PINGDRIVE

However, the script is not like this to run. It will loop back.
What's wrong? Is it related to "GOTO :EOF"? Please advise.
Thanks.

Code

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ping_Fail_A=1
SET ping_Fail_B=1
SET ping_Fail_C=1
SET num_Of_Attempts=1
----------------------------------------------------------

CALL :CLEANUP

CALL :PINGA

CALL :PINGB

CALL :PINGC

CALL :PINGD

CALL :PINGDRIVE

-----------------------------------------------------------

:CLEANUP
    
    IF EXIST "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\*.csv" (
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: File Found!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor MAGENTA"
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    DEL "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\*.csv"
 
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Clean Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
        
    ) ELSE (
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: File Not Found!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
        
    )

GOTO :EOF

:PINGA

    PING -n 1 192.168.1.100 | FIND "TTL" > NUL  

    IF errorlevel 1 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Network Disconnected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    SET /a ping_Fail_A=%ping_Fail_A%-1
    
    CALL :PINGB
    
    GOTO :EOF
    
    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Success! Network Connected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

CLS

    FOR /F %%a IN ('POWERSHELL -Nop -c "(Get-Date).Hour %% 2"') DO IF %%a EQU 1 (

    CALL :REDO_A

    ) ELSE (

    CALL :A
    
    )

)

GOTO :EOF

:PINGB

    PING -n 1 192.168.1.101 | FIND "TTL" > NUL  

    IF errorlevel 1 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Network Disconnected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    SET /a ping_Fail_B=%ping_Fail_B%-1
    
    CALL :PINGC
    
    GOTO :EOF
    
    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Success! Network Connected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

CLS

    FOR /F %%a IN ('POWERSHELL -Nop -c "(Get-Date).Hour %% 2"') DO IF %%a EQU 1 (

    CALL :REDO_B

    ) ELSE (

    CALL :B
    
    )

)

GOTO :EOF

:PINGC

    PING -n 1 192.168.1.102 | FIND "TTL" > NUL  

    IF errorlevel 1 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Network Disconnected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    SET /a ping_Fail_C=%ping_Fail_C%-1
    
    CALL :PINGD
    
    GOTO :EOF
    
    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Success! Network Connected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

CLS

    FOR /F %%a IN ('POWERSHELL -Nop -c "(Get-Date).Hour %% 2"') DO IF %%a EQU 1 (

    CALL :REDO_C

    ) ELSE (

    CALL :C
    
    )

)

GOTO :EOF

:PINGD

    PING -n 1 192.168.1.103 | FIND "TTL" > NUL  

    IF errorlevel 1 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Network Disconnected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    GOTO :EOF
    
    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Success! Network Connected!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

CLS

    FOR /F %%a IN ('POWERSHELL -Nop -c "(Get-Date).Hour %% 2"') DO IF %%a EQU 1 (

    CALL :REDO_D

    ) ELSE (

    CALL :D
    
    )

)

GOTO :EOF

:REDO_A
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.100/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'redo_A.csv'" > NUL

    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_REDO_A

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:REDO_B

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.101/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'redo_B.csv'" > NUL
    
    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_REDO_B

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:REDO_C

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.102/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'redo_C.csv'" > NUL
    
    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_REDO_C

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:REDO_D

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.103/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'redo_D.csv'" > NUL
    
    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_REDO_D

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:A
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.100/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'A.csv'" > NUL

    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_A

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:B

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.101/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'B.csv'" > NUL
    
    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_B

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:C

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.102/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'C.csv'" > NUL
    
    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_C

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:D

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.1.103/download.csv' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic ~!@#$%^&*()_+_\][' } -OutFile 'D.csv'" > NUL
    
    IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    GOTO RETRY_D

    ) ELSE (    
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Download Completed!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )
    
GOTO :EOF

:RETRY_A

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO A

    )

:RETRY_B

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO B

    )

:RETRY_C

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO C

    )

:RETRY_D

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO D

    )

:RETRY_REDO_A

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO REDO_A

    )

:RETRY_REDO_B

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO REDO_B

    )

:RETRY_REDO_C

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO REDO_C

    )

:RETRY_REDO_D

    IF %num_Of_Attempts% EQU 3 (

    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Maximum Retry Attempts Reached! Script End!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor CYAN"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    
    EXIT

    ) ELSE (

    SET /a num_Of_Attempts=%num_Of_Attempts%+1
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Go To Retry Again!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    POWERSHELL -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: Retry Attempts: %num_Of_Attempts% / 3' -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    CLS
    
    GOTO REDO_D

    )
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried? have you switched `@Echo off` to `@Echo on` and adding `Pause` periodically so you can see the execution of your script and determine where the logic failures are? Your script as it currently is very much the definition of spaghetti code. The lack of remarking and excessive use of call / goto make it a bit of a nightmare to determine what the intended script flow should be. It looks like most of the code could be eliminated by carfting a function with a set of paremeters to use for each of task a,b,c and d.

Comment: A reference that may provide a little insight on [approaching batch script design](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_bestpractices.php)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your code!

Comment: I've got to believe that this is more complicated and convoluted than needed. There are no RETRY_REDO_* labels. It looks like PowerShell is only used to download a file and write text with colors. Why not write the whole thing in PowerShell using `Test-Connection`?

Comment: @lit I''ve updated the part of RETRY_REDO_* and RETRY_* . Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @lit Yes. cmd batch-file does not support download file and write text with colours. Thanks.